# Linux - Handle interrupts on another cpu

Tags: linux, cpu, interrupt, smp

I'm trying to handle an interrupt with a group of cpus instead of the all available cpus in the system.
Basically, I want CPUs 32-63 to handle an interrupt while others interrupts are handled by CPUs 0-63.

If I'm not wrong, you are suppose to change files:
- **/proc/irq/X/smp_affinity**
- **/proc/irq/X/smp_affinity_list**
Where X is the interrupt number.

Right now, my files look like this:
**smp_affinity:** ffffffff,ffffffff
**smp_affinity_list:** 0-63

I want the second group of cores handling the interrupt. So, I should write:
**smp_affinity:** 00000000,ffffffff
**smp_affinity_list:** 32-63

Yet, it is not working:
**# echo "32-63" > /proc/irq/16/smp_affinity_list**
**bash: echo: write error: Input/output error**

/proc is correctly mounted with read/write permissions 
(proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)).
Using sudo to overwrite the values in the files.
The machine is running an Ubuntu 16.04, Linux kernel 4.4.0-96-generic.